# NGINX cors configuration does not apply

Tags: nginx

I have custom RTMP server on centos 6 with NGINX , I want to only allow origin to play or embed my stream links, X-Frame-Options works but the issue is Access-Control-Allow-Origin only works on chrome/Desktop, when I test with Microsoft Edge and mobile browsers (iOS/Android) i can still use and play my stream links .m3u8 on every domain !
I wonder why cors only apply on chrome but not other browsers?

this is my current nginx virtual conf file :

```
server {
listen       80;
server_name  domain.com www.domain.com;
location / {
root   /var/www/domain.net/public_html;
index  index.html index.htm;
try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'domain.com';
add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN" always;
}    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
root   html;
}
}
```